# How to take range from Vec without allocations and produce new Vec in Rust?

Tags: optimization, memory, rust

I would like to extract a range from a `Vec` by consuming it and returning a new Vec with only the required data. I would like for this to happen without needing to copy data or do any allocations. In C I would move pointers, change the length field and free memory as needed.

Currently I'm using [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) but I'm not sure of its performance characteristics (will it copy data?) or how idiomatic it is. For example, if I want the first 4 elements I'd do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

    // Only want to keep the first 4 elements
    let a: Vec<u32> = a.drain(..4).collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

I've seen the [`from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) method but if possible I would like to avoid fidgeting with pointers and the like.

Comment: You can look at the source of [drain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#1728-1730) to see what it's doing. Tip: When you're using https://doc.rust-lang.org, the `src` text on the right of a method is a link to the implementation of the method. I linked the source of `drain` by using the link you provided in your question.

Comment: If you want only the first 4 elements, you can use [vec.truncate(4)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General solutions require copying of data

In general, a `Vec` consists out of

1. an integer `capacity`
2. an area of memory that can contain `capacity` elements (I'll just call this the *buffer*) and
3. an integer `size`, with `size <= capacity`.

`capacity` is the number of elements the buffer *could* contain without resizing, `size` is the number of elements the buffer *does* currently contain.

The elements that are saved in the `Vec` are located at the beginning of the buffer (so, from index `0` to `size - 1`). This means that to create a new `Vec` that contains a subrange from the old `Vec`, in the general case, **some elements need to be copied** – if the subrange does not start at the first element, the first element in the new `Vec` will be different than the first element of the old `Vec`, you can't just reuse the buffer without copying.

In the case of `drain()`, this happens in [the Drop implementation of `Drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/vec/drain.rs.html#104):

```rust
                if self.0.tail_len > 0 {
                    unsafe {
                        let source_vec = self.0.vec.as_mut();
                        // memmove back untouched tail, update to new length
                        let start = source_vec.len();
                        let tail = self.0.tail_start;
                        if tail != start {
                            let src = source_vec.as_ptr().add(tail);
                            let dst = source_vec.as_mut_ptr().add(start);
                            ptr::copy(src, dst, self.0.tail_len);
                        }
                        source_vec.set_len(start + self.0.tail_len);
                    }
                }
```

## If you want to retain elements from the front

There is a solution without copying the elements if you want to only retain elements from the front and remove elements from the back. You can use [`truncate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate). You can [look at its source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#1019), it does not copy the data (and is, in my opinion, more idiomatic than using `drain()` in this case).

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    a.truncate(4);
    
    assert_eq!(a, vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aab813dc17075c570c4519a9e674c1fd)

For the sake of completeness: This does not shrink the capacity of the vector. If you are truncating a lot of elements and then keep the truncated `Vec` around without adding new elements, you are wasting memory. In that case, it may be a good idea to call [`shrink_to_fit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) after truncating (although this *may* copy the `Vec` content and is therefore more expensive).

`drain()` also should not copy data in this special case (`self.0.tail_len == 0` in that case, so the code snippet above does not get executed), but it is probably a bit more unclear compared to using `truncate` directly.